# Размер шрифта и отступы

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Никак не могу нагуглить следующие вопросы:

1. Откуда берётся этот отступ сверху над буквами и для каких целей он, в принципе, существует?
2. Можно ли от него избавиться?
3. Как грамотно высчитать отступ между, например, span и div, чтобы учесть этот зазор над текстом? Точнее, если мне нужен, например, отступ текста в 30рх сверху от блока, то как учесть этот самый зазор, который на большом кегеле имеет существенный размер.

   ```css
       span {
         font-size: 300px;
         line-height: 1;
         background: silver;
       }
   ```

   ```html
       <span>HojihtqgT</span>
   ```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Увы, у меня для Вас печальные известия. Эти отступы — «зарезервированные отступы шрифта», они сделаны специально для всяких «хвостиков» символов; поэтому, если их убрать, некоторые символы могут быть обрезаны. Его можно обрезать с помощью `line-height`, но это плохо, и не правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Это сам шрифт такой. Вот, добавил ещё 2 символа в строку - как видно, первый упирается ровно в границу, второй вообще не помещается в строке.

```css
body {
  padding: 40px 0;
}

span {
  font-size: 300px;
  line-height: 1;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<span>Ĝ█HojihtqgT</span>
```